# How to allow authorization scheme in specfic areas

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, .net-5

I use a cookie authentication scheme by default.
I have a specific area, where I would like to allow an additional authentication scheme, otherwise, all exiting policies should stay intact.

I have tried to add AuthoriztionFilter to IPageHandlerModelConvention/IControllerModelConvention:

```
public class AreaFiltersConvention : IPageHandlerModelConvention
{
    public string[] Areas { get; set; }


    public void Apply(PageHandlerModel model)
    {
        if (this.Areas.Contains(model.Page.AreaName))
        {
            model.Page.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter("AllowBasicAuthPolicy"));
        }
    }
```

I have two problems:

1. `PageHandlerModel.Page` is null, so I can't add AuthorizeFilter.
2. As far as I know, I can use it only to require a specific policy. I struggle with the OR condition.

   ```
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
         options.AddPolicy("AllowBasicAuthPolicy", policy =>
         {
              policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes("Basic"); // this breaks existing policies
              policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
         });
    });
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use build-in `AuthorizeAreaPage` convention in razor pages like below:

```
services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("AreaName", "/PageName", "AllowBasicAuthPolicy");
});
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/razor-pages-authorization?view=aspnetcore-5.0#require-authorization-to-access-an-area-page